# Azure AD Enterprise Applications User consent to company data

Tags: azure-active-directory

For Azure AD “Enterprise Applications”, is it possible to set “User can consent to apps accessing company data on their behalf” just for an app or does this have to be done for all apps in the tenant?

I am not the admin for my tenant but am registered user in my tenant.

The application is an existing application and has been registered in the developer’s tenant as a multi-tenant application. I am trying to get it to work in my tenant.

This application requires the following scopes:

- `files.readwrite`
- `files.readwrite.all`
- `offline_access`

I got the admin for my tenant to create a “service principal” in my tenant for this app by:

1. `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id22c49a0d-d21c-4792-aed1-8f163c982546&redirect_uri=http://localhost`
2. Sign in on as admin for my tenant

How can I set “User can consent to apps accessing company data on their behalf” just for an app in Azure AD Admin Center?

Also is there a website that shows all the screens in "Azure AD Admin Center"?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, developers should take a note on the [Microsoft Graph Permissions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference) and understand the difference between *delegated* and *application* permissions. Because there is a substantial difference. The developers of multi-tenant application should also understand how to generate [admin consent url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-scopes#using-the-admin-consent-endpoint) for requesting admin consent for their applications.

Secondly, if an Azure AD global administrator has configured the `User can consent to apps accessing company data on their behalf` option to false, then only Global Administrator can consent this application. This option is tenant wide and cannot be controlled on per-app basis. The only way through this is to talk to the tenant administrator, explain him what this application is doing and why you need it. Only the tenant administrator can grant the consent for this application to be used.

As for the screens of `Azure AD Admin Center` - there is no such website.

**UPDATE**

The option `Users can consent to application accessing company information on their behalf` is located under:

- https://aad.portal.azure.com
- Enterprise Applications
- Settings

And while this will work, it also work for any application in the future. Having this enabled had some purpose. It probably makes more sense to review the initial purpose, and if still valid to not change this value. If you wish to retain the value of the setting as is, you can talk to the developer of the application to give you an `admin consent` URL. Then you only need to give that URL to your global administrator and he has to open it, sign it and consent. Thus all your users will be able to use the application, while still keeping `Users can consent to applications accessing company data on their behalf` to **false**.

Comment: The admin for my tenant cannot find the parameter "User can consent to apps accessing company data on their behalf" within Azure AD Admin center . Can someone please tell me how to navigate to this switch in Azure AD Admin Center?

Comment: thx Anton !! I have a multi-tenant application but it is not configured for any permission that needs admin consent. However, while going through your answer, I realize that if AD tenant admin set this option to false then my application needs admin consent irrespective of configured permissions, is this understanding correct ?

Also setting this to false has any relation with V1 or V2/Converged app model ?  As per another [blog](https://blog.peterdahl.net/2018/05/14/azure-ad-v2-apps-vs-the-brick-wall/) seems this is specific to V2.

Comment: @RahulAgarwal, your understanding is correct. And the setting is **not** specific to any endpoint. The setting is tenant-wide and affects all applications and endpoints. The blog post is interesting but referring to a time-boxed issue, which shuould be solved by now.